# revoke create table on a user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I works on PostgreSQL.

I would like to create an user that can read/write on existing tables he don't own. This user is not the owner of any table, just a writer.

BUT I don't want this user can create any new table.

I would like to do something like that : 
"revoke create table on schema sch1 from myuser;"

Is it possible ?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Look at database roles.  If postgreSql does not have an existing one that's suitable, create your own.

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html)?

Comment: See this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115972/how-do-you-revoke-create-table-from-a-user-on-postgresql-9-4

Answer (score 1):

Create a user with no privileges at all. Then you can grant required privileges to the user.

e.g. GRANT ALTER, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT,
          UPDATE, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::myuser TO myuser;

More documentation here:
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/grant_revoke.php
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/why-is-a-new-user-allowed-to-create-a-table